# Oracle database multiple row -> c#

Tags: c#, oracle

How to retrieve multiple data rows from oracle database using c#.net? and disply the data rows to a list-box.

Comment: It is allowed to post an answer to a question you've asked on StackOverflow. But you must make sure that the question has not been asked previously and your answer is bulletproof. Otherwise, you should consider getting a blog instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's brush up your code:

```
// Extract methods, don't cram everything in OnClick
private void FeedFriendsListBox() {
  string oracleDb = @"connection string";

  //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
  using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oracleDb)) {
    conn.Open();

    //DONE: Make Sql readable - format it out and use names for the parameter(s)
    string sql =
      @"SELECT NAME, 
               ADDRESS  
          FROM FRIENDS 
         WHERE AGE = :prm _Age";

    //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn)) {
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(txtlist.Text, OracleDbType.Decimal));

      //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using 
      using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        if (!reader.HasRows) {
          listBox1.Text = "Not Found";

          MessageBox.Show("Data Not found", "NOT FOUND", 
                           MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

          return;
        }

        //DONE: Value is zero based
        //DONE: use formatting (string interpolation), not concatenating
        while (reader.Read())
          listBox1.Items.Add($"{reader.GetValue(0)} from {reader.GetValue(1)}");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then use extracted method:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  FeedFriendsListBox();   
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //database connection string and opening area
            string oracleDb = @"connection string";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oracleDb);
            conn.Open();

            //declareing paramater and readning parameter input
            OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter();
            param.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
            param.Value = txtlist.Text;

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            //sendting the parameter to the tabase query 
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NAME, ADDRESS  FROM FRIENDS WHERE age = :1";

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader dataread = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dataread.Read();

            if (dataread.HasRows)
            {
                while (dataread.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(dataread.GetString(1) + " from " + dataread.GetString(2));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Text = "Not Found";
                MessageBox.Show("Data Not found", "NOT FOUND", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            conn.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: And, even if you meant to post an example, your own self answer should not be considerd as a good answer because there is a big problem here. What happens if an exception occurs somewhere in this code? You will leave your connection open and undisposed leading to serious resources leaking. Please understand how the using statement works.

Comment: Just seen another problem. Did you even try to run this code at least one time?
 This code blows up in your face at the first loop. You retrieve two columns and then use a wrong index when retrieving data. IndexOutOfRangeException will occur at GetString(2)-